# React Native SMS Linking override draft message

Tags: react-native, sms, react-native-linking

I'm trying to send a message via react-native `Linking`

```js
const sendSms = async (phoneNumber, message) => {
  const separator = Platform.isIos ? '&' : '?'
  const url = `sms:${phoneNumber}${separator}body=${message}`

  await Linking.openURL(url)
}
```

**expected behavior:**

- sms app is opened and the message is populated inside a field

**actual behavior:**

- when I already had a conversation with this person via SMS and have a message in the draft, sms app opened but the message is not populated. Instead old unfinished message takes priority